# In Google Analytics e-commerce data, should the product price include tax?

Tags: google-analytics, ecommerce

Should the product price include tax in Google Analytics e-commerce data?   Is that tax then tracked separately?

Comment: Referring to Google's documentation you shouldn't: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce#measuring-transactions Notice how 37.39 - 2.85 - 5.34 = 29.20, so taxes are excluded from price.
It's not deliberatly mentioned, but this is all there is.

Comment: Come to think of it, if you sell products to different markets VATs might differ as well. Hence, prices will for the same SKU will be different too making analysis harder, if you incorporate taxes.